# open gles basic class structures

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-activity, glsurfaceview

I have four classes to understand opengles at my first opengles education:

- myRenderer
- myGLSurfaceViev
- myActivity
- myTriangle

I want to get touch events on my surface.. but after ı set myRenderer, ı see my triangle on the screen but ı cant get touch event.

If I set mySurfaceView first without myRenderer in myActivity, ı get touch events.. but ı cant see my triangle.

What is the mistake here?

Comment: Can you please show the code you are using? We can't answer without having some idea of what you're doing.

Comment: ı tried to send my all code, soo much. but finally, ı left it. Stack didnt accept my very tall code..  :)

Comment: ı can send with email..  if some friends want it..

Comment: You need to trim the code down to only the relevant parts. Perhaps the SurfaceView onCreate methods, and any onTouch/onTouchEvents that you have overridden, plus anything else you think that might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You could write in "Render" like this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    // codes here
}
```

then add event codes in myActivity like this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    myRender.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

i could see View and get touch event in my codes.
So, what about you?

Comment: ı have onTouchEvent in mySurfaceView and ı have your second code part in onTouchEvent in mySurfaceView..  but ı still cant get touch events in my renderer...  Even stacks doesnt accept my code  and ı cant share my code sample here..  ı tried again just now..  but it didnt accept again..  :))) ı think, ı have an unaccebtable code in all world..  :D

Comment: i am sorry that it doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented `onTouchEvent` on `GLSurfaceView` and sent events to `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`. You can implement `onTouchEvent` on `myGLSurfaceViev`.

Can I read your codes via here, gist, github repository or email?